# javascript prototype chain Object vs function Object

Tags: javascript

I probably did not make the title correctly but please someone explain why I can't create prototype for person object? Only works when I put hit to Object.prototype chain.

```
const person = {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function () {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
  }
};

//person.prototype.hit = function(){
//    console.log("hitting me");
//}

Object.prototype.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me");
}

const me = Object.create(person);

me.name = "Matthew"; // "name" is a property set on "me", but not on "person"
me.isHuman = true; // inherited properties can be overwritten

me.printIntroduction();
me.hit();
```

(UPDATE) . Why does THIS work?? Not sure what the differences are actually from this example but this code works.

```
function person {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function () {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
  }
}();

person.prototype.hit = function(){

    console.log("hitting me");
}

/*
person.prototype.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me");
}
*/

Object.prototype.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me");
}

const me = Object.create(person);

me.name = "Matthew"; // "name" is a property set on "me", but not on "person"
me.isHuman = true; // inherited properties can be overwritten

me.printIntroduction();
me.hit();
// expected output: "My name is Matthew. Am I human? true"
```

### update 2

Ok, so I make it work like below but clearly prototype doesn't work the way I expected.. so I am clearly confused about prototype

```
function person(){
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
}

person.prototype.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me1");
}

Object.prototype.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me2");
}

const me = Object.create(person);

me.hit();
```

UPDATE 3.

thank you.. this is the explanation that I got from below.. thank you and this is clear now.

```
function person(){
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
}

person.prototype.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me1");
}

Object.prototype.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me2");
}

//const me = Object.create(person);
const me = new person;

me.hit();
```

Comment: It's one of the confusing parts of javascript: `x.prototype` and `prototype of x` are different things.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: Can you look at my update to see why THIS works?

Comment: @user3502374 through your edit it became an exact duplicate :)

Comment: @user3502374 In your update, `function person {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function () {…}
}();` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi, it works for me.. I don't know what you mean by syntax error. (SORRY, it does not.. damn)

Comment: one more update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would do this (quite similar to what you are doing):

```
 const person = {
   isHuman: false,
   printIntroduction: function () {
     console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
   },
   prototype: {
     hit(){ console.log("hutting me"); }
   }
 };
```

Then when you instantiate your object got a prototype property:

```
 const me = Object.create(person);
 me.prototype.hit();
```

The inheritance chain is:

```
 me -> person -> Object.prototype
```

And NOT:

```
 me -> person -> person.prototype -> Object.prototype
```

The `prototype` property actually hasnt to do much with inheritance, just imagine that it would not exist.

---

However it is important when talking about *constructors*. When you call a function with `new` in front, it is treated as a constructor, e.g.:

```
 var me = new Person()
```

And that is just syntactic sugar for:

```
 var me = Object.create(Person.prototype /*!!!*/);
 Person.call(me);
```

So when you set up a *function*, set its *prototype* property and call it with `new`, only then the prototype property of the constructor gets part of the instances prototype chain:

```
function Person(){}

Person.prototype.hit = () => console.log("works");

const me = new Person();
 me.hit();
```

Now the chain is:

```
me -> Person.prototype -> Object.prototype
```

Comment: I added another comment 3.. this is the right explanation. thank you.

Comment: @user3502374 glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I create prototype for person object?

Because `person` does not have a `.prototype` property, and doesn't need one.

The `person` object already has a prototype from which it inherits: `Object.prototype` (the default for all object literals). You shouldn't change that though.

Also, `person` does act as a prototype for the `me` object (i.e. `me` inherits from `person`). So if you want to give it another method, you should just write

```
person.hit = function(){
    console.log("hitting me");
};
```

that puts the `hit` function as a property of `person` in exactly the same way that `printIntroduction` is.

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Because JS is trying to access to a property called `prototype` rather than a "prototype" of that object.

To define a prototype, you need to use the function `setPrototypeOf()`

```js
const person = {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function() {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(person, {
  'hit': function() {
    console.log("hitting me");
  }
});

const me = Object.create(person);

me.name = "Matthew"; // "name" is a property set on "me", but not on "person"
me.isHuman = true; // inherited properties can be overwritten

me.printIntroduction();
me.hit();
```

Or, you can declare that function directly into the object `person`

```js
const person = {
  isHuman: false,
  printIntroduction: function() {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name}. Am I human? ${this.isHuman}`);
  },
  'hit': function() {
    console.log("hitting me");
  }
};

const me = Object.create(person);

me.name = "Matthew"; // "name" is a property set on "me", but not on "person"
me.isHuman = true; // inherited properties can be overwritten

me.printIntroduction();
me.hit();
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not really what the OP needs/wants.

Comment: @Bergi can you explain what the OP wants?

Comment: OP wants to call `me.hit();` - I don't know more. I don't think they want to add another level to the prototype chain, nothing in the question hints at that. Your second snippet is a much better solution, `Object.setPrototypeOf` should be avoided.

Comment: @Bergi umm right, got it

Comment: Oh, overriding `Object.prototype` ... interesting. `12..hit()` ...

Comment: one more update